# Does the Taylor Polynomial approximation work for non-convergent functions?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The approximation of $f(x)$ by $P_{n}(x)$ at $c$ has an error of $R_{n}(x) =  \frac{f^{n+1}(z) (x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$. Does this work for any $(n+1)$ differentiable function even if it doesn't have a power series representation, i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty}{R_{n}} \neq 0$?

Comment: Once you write the precise statement (see the following link), yes. This is the classical statement of [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable) with the [Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder).

Comment: I think that you should make this an answer, rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  Taylor's theorem with various remainder estimates do not depend on the function being analytic. They only require sufficiently many (perhaps continuous) derivatives to exist. If a function is not analytic, the asymptotic behavior of the remainder as $n\to\infty$ will not be very nice, but well-chosen   values of $n$ may serve the approximation purpose just fine.